# how to pass group id to custom loss function in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

My samples have group id. Is there any way that I pass the group id to my keras model and calculate the loss according to group id?

Comment: Welcome to the community :) In order to receive an acurate and helpful answer to your question you need to make sure write a concise question along with the code that shows your situation and what you have tried. Stackoverflow is **not** a code writing service but merely serves as an aid. If you haven't given it a try yourself I suggest you do some more research, make a valiant attempt and if that still doesn't work out you can come back **with your code** and ask for some pointers :)

Comment: It seems keras doesn't support passing a groupid for samples. that's why I asked here

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the group label as a dummy column in the target vector y and exclude it from the loss. The following code calculates the mean squared error for each group and returns the largest value.

```
def worst_case_group_mse(y_true, y_pred):
   """calculate mean squared error for each group separately and return worst value

    Args:
        y_true, y_pred (tf.Tensor): 
            last column corresponds to group index, 
            mean squared error calculated over all other columns

    Returns:
        tf.Tensor: maximum grouped mean squared error
    """
    groups = tf.cast(y_true[:,-1], tf.int32)
    y_true, y_pred = y_true[:,:-1], y_pred[:,:-1]

    square = tf.math.square(y_pred - y_true)
    unique, idx, count = tf.unique_with_counts(groups)
    group_losses = tf.math.unsorted_segment_mean(square, idx, tf.size(unique))
    group_losses = tf.math.reduce_mean(group_losses, axis=1)
    return tf.math.reduce_max(group_losses)
```